# How do I refer to the values of another Maven plugin's configuration?

Tags: maven

In my specific case I'm looking to use the value of the WAR plugin's <webappDirectory> setting as configuration to an execution of the dependency plugin.

Is there a general way to refer to the WAR plugin's settings as a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You'd need to have both plugins reference a property that you define in your pom to achieve this... and in such cases any pom overriding the configuration but not the property would cause issues.